# ¿Como crear un server de tmodloader en github codespaces?

Tags: github, server

Recientemente estaba jugando en un servidor de terraria con mods pero mi pc se quedo corto de recursos, se me ocurrió de la idea de utilizar codespaces para hostear el server y jugar desde mi pc
No se mucho del tema pero estuve viendo como implemtarlo en el bash de codespaces con varios docker de uso  libre y un server web llamado ngrok que hace la funcion de hamachi con el forwarding de puertos. aqui en el repositorio esta un intento que hice

https://github.com/luisfer153/loader